# converting varchar2 to number does not produce right ORDER of results

Tags: sql, oracle10g

Hello I am working on an oracle DB which has table id as varchar2 which actually holds numbers only e.g. 2000, 30201. Now I need to compare these values as numbers so I use the TO_NUMBER() function but the results still come out unsuccessfull. Example code is below. Any help is deeply appreciated.

```
SELECT ID FROM facty WHERE to_number(ID)>2 ORDER BY ID
```

current result:
**11, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9**

**I need it to produce 4, 5, 6, 8, 9,11**

Comment: Why are you storing numbers as text? This is inefficient and also causes lots of problems when one of your IDs is an invalid number.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use Oracle,  but I'm guessing you need to include the `to_number(id)` on the `ORDER BY` as well.  Your current query `ORDER BY` uses the varchar field, not the numeric conversion.

Comment: Thanks for TIP!! I tried ORDER BY TO_NUMBER(ID) and it works.

Comment: I know its not conventional and it makes life so much more difficult but that is the current data dictionary of a firm (legacy stuff) and some values later end up with ALPHABETS eg 'A302' and some just pure '30201'. I just have to stick to it ..for now.